# Adding a Prefix to a Value to make a link

Tags: php

I'm returning a tracking number from a database and would like to make it a clickable link.

```
<td><?php echo $row['tracking_number']; ?></td>
```

PREFIX is "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums="

http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=TRACKINGNUMBER

Comment: `$prefix . $trackingNumber`

Comment: It's better to use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php): `'http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?' . http_build_query(['track' => 'yes', 'trackNums' => $trackNums]);` It will automatically encode data as urlencoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below the line for this requirement

```
echo "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums="
    . $row['tracking_number'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$link='http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums='

$link.=$row['tracking_number'];
```

Answer (score -2):

Building on the comment by marv255:

```php
<td>
    <?php
        $link_href = 'http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?'
            . http_build_query(['track' => 'yes', 'trackNums' => $$row['tracking_number']]);
        echo '<a href="' . $link_href . '">' . $row['tracking_number'] . '</a>'; 
    ?>
</td>
```

If `$row['tracking_number']` is a string no further alteration is needed, but if it is an array of tracking numbers then `$tracking_numbers = implode(',', $row['tracking_number']);` could be inserted and `$tracking_numbers` would replace the usages of `$row['tracking_number']);`.